# How do you accept file uploads in noir

Tags: clojure, noir

I have a file input setup like this

```
[:p "Upload a book"]
      (form-to [:post "/upload"]
               (file-upload :book)
               (submit-button "Upload"))
```

My upload endpoint then looks like this.

```
(defpage [:post "/upload"] {:keys [book]} (println book))
```

book just seems to be a string of the title of the file that was uploaded and not the file itself. How do I get the file?

Answer (score 4):

According to this thread (see second post by Chris Granger):

- http://groups.google.com/group/clj-noir/browse_thread/thread/58e45ad02bb21571

you can use something like:

```
(defpage [:post "upload"] {:keys [myFile]}
  (println myFile) ;; see all the things the file contains
  (io/copy (io/file (:tempfile myFile)) (io/file "uploads/some-new-name")))
```

Here's a gist from this thread:

- https://gist.github.com/1315692

with a note (again from Chris) that you need Leiningen 1.6.1.1+ not to run into a bug.

You can see a similar thing (though for Amazon S3) here:

- http://francesco-cek.com/uploading-a-file-to-amazon-s3-using-clojure-and-noir-2/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're accepting fine; I believe you're posting wrong. Try `form-to {:enctype "multipart/form-data"}`, or from the shell `curl --form book=@/home/me/Penguins.jpg http://localhost:8080/Upload`